# Server Sent Event not working in Google Chrome

Tags: java, html, jsp, dom-events, server-sent-events

This is my server JSP code "Server_Date.jsp"

```
<%
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); 
response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
out.print("data: " + (new java.util.Date()).toString() + "x\n\n");
out.flush();   
%>
```

This my client jsp page "Client_Serverdate.jsp"

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body  onload="begin()">
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>
<script >
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{     
var source=new EventSource("Server_Date.jsp");      
source.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
}, false);
}
else
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me this code is working fine in Mozilla Firefox, Opera but not working in Google Chrome (I was checked with 18.x and 20.x also).

It is going to server page I have checked with print statement but its not coming to the line `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;`.

Comment: May be chrome will be having problem with the new-line('\n').Try without '\n'.

Comment: @RaviJain i have checked with out \n also. if i alert() before source.addEventListener() is prompt, but inside function its not prompt... plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved

Solution :

Page encoding problem : client side used UTF-8 Encoding

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Server side UTF-8 was not mention, so after adding charset=UTF-8 in setContentType its working

```
response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
```

Thanks for people take your effort to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

For one you are calling a function `begin()` that is not defined although that should not be the issue here.

Does the Chrome development console show any errors? It should show at least one. because of the begin function. And does the network tab show traffic to Server_Date.jsp?

Comment: Chrome development console show any errors? No there is no errors in chrome console... It is invoking Server_Date.jsp but data which is return by that file is not print in Client_Serverdate.jsp file

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same issue. As server part, I used PHP, but I guess it works the same. What fixed it for me was adding `ob_flush()`. Now, I don't know what it should be in your language, but maybe it helps you in the right direction.

Comment: alternative of ob_flush(), in jsp is out.flush() only but its not working with chrome only thats its my problem ... help me...

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same problem, and i resolved it by add a newline at the end of the servlet.
like this:

```
response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("data: " + new Date());
out.println();
out.flush();
out.close();
```