# Server-sent events not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am trying to update a specific element in my HTML document using server-sent events. I am using the [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) with parameters changed to fit my needs. When this did not work out of the box, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329233/server-sent-event-not-working-in-google-chrome) question's solution, which is to include `charset=utf-8` in my Content-Type header. Still no updates to the HTML. I then realized I was getting the following error:

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Here is the relevant JavaScript in my .js file:

```
var source = new EventSource("warehouse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("processing").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

In my PHP file, I have the following:

```
if (isset($args->products)) {
    orderProducts($args->products);
}

function orderProducts($products) {
    $bigResponse = outgoingData(constant('bigURL'), $products[0]);
    $littleResponse = outgoingData(constant('lilURL'), $products[3]);

    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    echo "data: Order has been placed.";
    flush();        
}
```

I am completely stumped. What am I missing? How do I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe there's an error in the code or in the returned message somewhere. What's the complete response you're getting?

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the browser console? Add an `onerror` handler to `source` as well.

Comment: @SeanBright The only error I am getting is the one I posted in my question.

Comment: @networkdrift, even after adding the `onerror` handler?

Comment: @SeanBright Yes. `onerror` does update the browser, however.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending a json encoded data part/element back to the browser.

Lets see if I can remember correctly... It's out of my mind, so it isn't tested!

PHP Side:

```
// Set SSE headers which are send along first output.
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=UTF-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$sseId = 0;           //Increment this value on each next message
$event = 'eventName'; //Name of the event which triggers same named event-handler in js.
//$data needs to be json encoded. It can be a value of any type.
$data = array ('status' => 'Progress', 'message' => 'My message or html');

//Send SSE Message to browser
echo 'id: ' . $sseId++ . PHP_EOL;             //Id of message
if (!is_null($event)) {
    echo 'event: ' . $event . PHP_EOL;        //Event Name to trigger eventhandler
}
retry: 10000 . PHP_EOL;                       //Define custom reconnection time. (Default to 3s when not specified)
echo 'data: ' . json_encode($data) . PHP_EOL; //Data to send to eventhandler
//Note: When sending html, you might need to encode with flags: JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG

echo PHP_EOL;
ob_flush();
flush();
```

JavaScript side:

```
var es = new EventSource('sse.php');
es.addEventListener('eventName', function(event) {
    var returnData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var myElement = document.getElementById("processing");
    switch (returnData.status) {
        case 'Error':
            es.close();
            myElement.innerHTML = 'An error occured!';
            break;
        case 'Done':
            es.close();
            myElement.innerHTML = 'Finished!';
            break;
        case 'Progress':
            myElement.innerHTML += returnData.message  + "<br>";
            break;
    }
});

es.onerror = function() {
    console.log("EventSource failed.");
};
```

In this case I make use of 1 (named) event only where the data element contains a status on which js reacts.

You can also define multiple event-names to be used as a status and define corresponding event-handlers or define a handler which is triggered on each message received.

```
es.onmessage = function(event) {
    //This handler fires on each message received.
    console.log("Incoming message.");
};
```

If you have server-side script running longer then 3s, specify a longer retry time in the message sent (See code at PHP side). Otherwise the browser will reconnect after 3 seconds which might run your script from the beginning and abandon the previous run.

Comment: Very detailed answer, but looks like I'm still getting the error I posted upon loading the page.

Comment: The php script must be sending html in your case (which it will when you have errors in your script). Are you sure nothing is displayed in the preview or response tab for the corresponding request of the network developer tools?